# счетчик в Navigation drawer

Tags: android

У меня есть CustomView которая выполняет роль NavigationDrawer и постоянно отображается на всех страницах приложения. В приложении есть возможность добавлять товар в корзину(корзина в правом углу на скрине), вопрос, как мне добавить счетчик к корзине чтобы при добавлении товара он увеличивался и отображался ...какой элемент использовать? Сейчас у меня есть вот такой элемент
[image: Скриншот]

А должно получиться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:

Сделал иконку корзины отдельным Layout и добавил в него ImageView и TextView(он и является счетчиком), если не верно сделал - исправьте

Answer (score 0):

С помощью статической переменной и метода можно добиться успеха. 
А чтобы сохранить данные используйте SharedPreferences.Editor